# PDO statement puts all the params the same

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following function that searches a database:

```
public function search($table, $column, $term, $limit = 0, $offset = 0){
        $command = "SELECT * FROM `$table`";
        $size = 1; //1 is for when there is only one LIKE 
         if(is_array($column)){ //Creates the array statemenet
             $size = sizeof($column);
             for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
                 if($i == 0){
                     $command.=" WHERE `$column[$i]` LIKE ?";
                 }else{
                     $command.=" AND `$column[$i]` LIKE ?";
                 }
             }
        }else{//If there's only one
            $command.=" WHERE $column LIKE ?";
        }

    if($limit > 0){//Adds limits
        $command.=" LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
    }

    echo $command;
    $query = $this->connection->prepare($command);

    if(is_array($column)){
        $x = 0;

        foreach($term as $coldata){
            $x++;
            $type;
            $coldata = "%{$coldata}%";
            $query->bindParam($x, $coldata, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
    }else{
        $term = "%{$term}%";
        $query->bindParam(1, $term,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    if($limit > 0){
        $query->bindParam($size + 1, $limit,  PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam($size + 2, $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }

    $query->execute();
    return ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}
```

and the $column and $term parameters of the function can be an array. If they are an array, the function will do a

```
WHERE x LIKE y AND z LIKE b
```

type thing.

However, when I test it, it does something like this:

```
Where x LIKE b AND z LIKE b
```

All of the LIKE parameters are the same. Here is the example data I provided:

```
$table="tableName"
$column=array('member','type')
$term=array('Bob','admin')
$limit=30
$offset=0
```

When I check my query logs, I get this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE `member` LIKE '%admin%' AND `type` LIKE '%admin%' LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

Why does it use admin on both of them and not Bob then Admin like so

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE `member` LIKE '%Bob%' AND `type` LIKE '%admin%' LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: I get admin bob and admin... https://eval.in/436021

Comment: The duplicate answer was correct! Using ->bindValue instead of ->bindParam worked. I never thought of trying to switch it. Thank!